# Stray end tag "head"

Tags: html, netbeans, tags

I have the following html5 code:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link href="Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 
    <title>Catalogo Dischi</title>
        <p class="title"> Catalogo Dischi </p>
    <a id="index">
        <p class="subtitle">Indice</p>
    </a>
    <p class="text">
        <a href="#classic">Musica Classica</a>
        <br/>
        <a href="#jazz">Musica Jazz</a>
        <br/>
        <a href="#country">Musica Country</a>
    </p>
</head>
```

**The code is inside the html tag**. I don't understand the reason of this error, I close all tags except for meta and link, which can't be closed, what's the problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you need to understand -- the `<head>` element defines attributes that are used by the browser, but are not directly visible in the page. The `<title>` attribute defines the title shown on your browser tab.

After you close the `<head>` tag, you should open the `<body>` tag, in which all the content to be shown in the page should go.

Also see http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/page-structure for a basic introduction to these elements.

Answer (score 7):

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link href="Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 
    <title>Catalogo Dischi</title>

</head>

<body>

    <p class="title"> Catalogo Dischi </p>
    <a id="index">
        <p class="subtitle">Indice</p>
    </a>
    <p class="text">
        <a href="#classic">Musica Classica</a>
        <br/>
        <a href="#jazz">Musica Jazz</a>
        <br/>
        <a href="#country">Musica Country</a>
    </p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to close the `head` tag after your title and wrap your content in `body` tags.

Answer (score 2):

Error may occured if there is an issue of type or double tab in head section. suppose title is like this

```
    <title> Foundation </title>>
```

Then Stray end tag “head” will occur including error in body

If page opened in Chrome then it will add a > right after 'Body' tag

```
<body>
">"
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have placed `<p>` inside `<head>` when the

starts it indicates body part but
so after

all thing goes under body so closing `</head>` is an error

Answer (score 0):

This is your charset  `charset=UTF-8"` it's missing the `"` at the beginning.

Comment: I think this line is actually correct: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`

Answer (score 0):

i solved mine by doing this to my code i show you the tag example so you can see what i did to the tags.

so with a link tag it would be:

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Aclonica%7cPlayfair+Display' rel='stylesheet'/>
```

notice on the end the link tag just ends with />